# python getting instance variables best practice

Tags: python

I was wondering how should one access the instance variables in a python class. Should i make a method for every instance variable or should i access them directly?

Here's an example:

```
class Example(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5

    def getX(self):
        return self.x

    def addYtoX(self, y):
        return self.x + y # OR: return self.getX() + y
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mostly, just access them directly. Python [is *not* Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html).

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5

    def addYtoX(self, y):
        return self.x + y
```

In Java, you have to use getters and setters because you cannot change your mind and change the public fields to getters and setters later on. In python, you can, so don't use getters and setters until you have an actual need to. Then you switch to a [`property`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) instead.

Comment: Thank you. But what if i have a  superclass that contains a constructor that initializes some instance variables. Should i then, inside a subclass, still access them direcly?

Comment: What he said, just use them directly. If, later on, you want to modify/ control how the values are returned, Python provides [Descriptors](http://martyalchin.com/2007/nov/23/python-descriptors-part-1-of-2/) so you can override the behavior even though code is calling the properties directly.

Comment: @geekkid: You still access them directly, yes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I gave you an upvote, but you should watch your mouth with `"Python is not Java"` - C++ people might get angry! :> Just kiddin', but no really, just cause you're used to Java doesn't mean everyone else does. You can't really expect everyone to come from Java background. But still a good answer, just wanted to make a note ^^

Comment: @Mahi: I don't come from a Java background actually. Instead, I've managed to avoid Java for 17 years now. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters See? I did exactly what I told you not to do; I expected you to come from Java background. Not a good thing from me, sorry for misunderstanding. However, you understood my point. :-) It gets annoying after a while, when people keep telling you "Dude this is not Java" or "I hate you Java coders", when I've been coding C++ for like 3 years, and have never touched Java in my life.

Comment: @Mahi: Most often we see this insistence to use getters and setters when the person learning python has a Java background.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Maybe that's a proof of C++ users being more intelligent, realizing not to use setters and getters on their own, even tho they're required in C++ ;) Just kidding :D who knows.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no reason to provide any form of checking, then Python allows you to add/remove/set the value directly

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_var = 5

a = A()
a.other_var = 6

print a.some_var
a.some_var = 123456
del a.some_var
```

etc...

Otherwise, you can use setters/getters (but only if your design justifies it):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
         self._some_var = 5 # note the _
    @property
    def some_var(self):
        return self._some_var

    @some_var.setter
    def some_var(self, val):
        if val > 5:
            self._some_var = val
        else:
            print 'Nope - can not do that!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and just access `x` directly.  If, at some later time, you decide you need to encapsulate `x`, do type/value-checking, etc., then you can convert it to a [property attribute](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property), which allows you to define the get/set methods without having to change any of your existing client code.